# Can someone calculate the age of the KOI-4878 star?

Tags: star, age

The star’s low metallicity and fairly high space velocity suggest that KOI-4878 is older than the Sun.

But I don't know how to calculate an estimation for the age.

[KOI-4878 data on Simbad](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=KOI-4878&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit+id)

Comment: You probably want to look if it has been picked up by an asteroseismic survey. Given that its a KOI, this could be true. Ages from asteroseismology are the most accurate ones, particularly that this star is a G4.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Where would one look for that?

Comment: @B--rian: I would think the relevant archives should be those with accurately sampled photometric time series data, i.e. Corot, Kepler, Tess. But I see you already posted the link to the exoplanet archive, which does link all those info together, if available. If standard methods (isochrone fitting, seismology) would allow the age determination, I suspect it would already have been done.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Thanks for the hints, made me realize that I do not understand the [exoplanet archive](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/DisplayOverview/nph-DisplayOverview?objname=KOI-4878&type=KEPLER_TARGET) well enough - all I see is that there is no obvious entry *age*.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia on KOI-4878.01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI-4878.01) **nobody did yet calculate the age of that object**, but says exactly what you quoted:

> its low metallicity and fairly high space velocity suggest that KOI-4878 is older than the Sun.

This supposidely relies on the following sources:

- https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/DisplayOverview/nph-DisplayOverview?objname=KOI-4878&type=KEPLER_TARGET
- https://www.drewexmachina.com/2019/09/05/koi-4878-01-keplers-most-earth-like-planet-candidate/

A search with the keyword `KOI-4878.01` on different publication databases like [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=KOI-4878.01&searchtype=all&source=header) or [scholar.google](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=KOI-4878.01&btnG=) did not help either.

#### Related

- [How do scientists determine the age of stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/942/how-do-scientists-determine-the-age-of-stars) focuses on the general question how to determine the age of a star.